# How to deal with numbers in groovy

Tags: java, groovy

I've got the following snippet of code:

```
mystring = "1.43 something something"
def foo = mystring =~ /(\d*.\d*).*/
def number = foo[0][1]
number = (int)(number * 2.54)
```

The above code fails with exception: `Cannot cast object '1.431.43' with class 'java.lang.String' to class 'int'`

However, If I change the last line to: `number = (int)(Double.parseDouble(number) * 1.54)` then everything seems to work fine.

What is the best way to do this in groovy?

`(int)(Double.parseDouble(number)` does work but is a bit verbose and javaish.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can convert the number to a double with `as double`:

```
def number = foo[0][1] as double
number = (int)(number * 2.54)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
def number = foo[0][1] as double
```

or

```
def number = foo[0][1].toDouble()
```

Check [the Groovy Cookbook](http://groovycookbook.org/basic_types/numbers/) for more information.